# Mysql Join query with count() for getting user favourites posts

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my DB

1.USER TABLE

2.POST table (id,title)

3.FAVOURITE TABLE (id,post_id,user_id)

I want to get post that favourite by a particular user along with total favourites of each post.

```
SELECT post.title,COUNT(favourite.post_id) as total_favourites FROM post
JOIN favourite ON post.id=favourite.post_id
WHERE favourite.user_id=119 GROUP BY favourite.post_id
```

I got the result but there is a problem with `total_favourites` its always give count as `1` even if there is more than one favourite for particular post.

for eg:

favourite table

```
 id post_id,user_id
   1  1       1
   1  1       2
```

in the above post has id `1` have two favourites but in my query i will get count as `1`

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)`  instead of `COUNT(favourite.post_id)`

Comment: Let me try that one

Comment: @AlivetoDie still i got the same

Answer (score 0):

An user only can mark as favourite a post one time, so the total count always be 1.

Comment: But a post have more than one favourites think like fb post and like

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping by user_id instead.